# AngularJs ngNotify dismiss on click

Tags: angularjs, ngnotify

I have been asked to add dismiss on click functionality to our notifications (which are served up by ngNotify). I thought this would be a simple task, but I cannot find this functionality by default.
At first I created a directive that targeted the class **ngn-sticky**. It was simply this:

```
angular.module('sapphire.directives').directive('ngnSticky', directive);

function directive(ngNotify) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: lnkFn
    };

    function lnkFn(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        element.on('click', function (e) {
            ngNotify.dismiss();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
};
```

But this did not work. I added a button to the page with the notification and gave it the class **ngn-sticky** and that did work, but that was no the desired effect.
So, I though that maybe I can override the template like we do with **angular-bootstrap**, so I looked into the actual directive and found that it has no **templateUrl** to override.

Does anyone know how I can override the template? Or somehow add an onclick method to any ngNotify message?

Comment: So you want the sticky notification to dismiss when clicking anywhere on the notification? Im asking because according to the documentation (https://github.com/matowens/ng-notify) a sticky notification already has a dismiss button

Comment: yeah, but it is a button. I want the whole thing to be clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the template is not a good solution, as you then implicitly depend on the internals of the external library!

Anyhow, [in their source code](https://github.com/matowens/ng-notify/blob/master/src/scripts/ng-notify.js#L91) you can see a template being put into the `$templateCache`.

```
function ngNotifyCache($templateCache) {

    var html =
    '<div class="ngn" ng-class="ngNotify.notifyClass">' +
        '<span ng-if="ngNotify.notifyHtml" class="ngn-message" ng-bind-html="ngNotify.notifyMessage"></span>' + // Display HTML notifications.
        '<span ng-if="!ngNotify.notifyHtml" class="ngn-message" ng-bind="ngNotify.notifyMessage"></span>' + // Display escaped notifications.
        '<span ng-show="ngNotify.notifyButton" class="ngn-dismiss" ng-click="dismiss()">&times;</span>' +
    '</div>';

    $templateCache.put(TEMPLATE, html);
}
```

You should be able to override that by just putting in a new template with a the same key. Just the proper timing needs to be found out. The new template would need a `ng-click` attribute at the whole div I assume.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache